# mysql sort question

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a database and I want to sort the a column according to the number of words included in each field.

Ex:

```
a b (has 2 words)
a b c d e (has 5 words)
a b c (has 3 words)
```

And i want 'a b c d e' to be the first in sort result, and 'a b c' the second. .. etc

Do you have a solution fot it?

Edit: Thanks guys for quicly answers!
All answers was good but meanwhile i solved using same sollutions found here [mysql-substr-count](http://nostylesheets.com/2009/07/17/mysql-substr-count/)

Comment: Seriously, ditch that schema. If you ever find yourself having to individually process items _within_ a column, you've done the wrong thing.

Comment: the solution you found at your link was given in the answers already …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick, but maybe there's a better (faster) solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY LENGTH(column) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column, ' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hum - [here](http://www.mwasif.com/2008/12/count-number-of-words-in-a-mysql-column/)'s an example on how to count words in one column. Maybe it can be extended like this

```
SELECT 
    SUM( LENGTH(`name`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`name`, ' ', ''))+1) AS `num_words`
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `num_words`
```

(not tested - sorry.)

Comment: That will count the number or words in all records, not sort the result on the number of word in each record.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the number of spaces:

```
order by length(field) - length(replace(field, ' ', '')) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely wrong with your database structure. if you ask such a question.
Such a numbers ought to be taken from the database structure, not field contents.
As immediate result of such a bad design is terrible performance of all the queries from the answers above.